# Joomla model associations

Tags: joomla

I have been working with CakePHP which has model associations such as hasMany, belongsTom etc...

Now I am working with Joomla and need this type of functionality.

All I need is a point the right direction such as a link describing it as I cannot seem to find something about it on Google.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There' is a world of difference between the two, and goes far beyond a simple answer on SO.  The [API Docs](http://api.joomla.org/) are quite extensive, and there are many decent examples.  [Developing a Model-View-Controller (MVC) Component for Joomla!2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5) will likely also give you some good reference. Additionally, with 9000+ open source extensions available, it's usually quite easy to find one that comes close to what you want to do in order to have some sample code to work from.